# Import All Access 2016 tables into SAS 9.4 (from multiple .accdb DBs)

Tags: ms-access, import, sas, sas-macro

I am trying to import all tables from a multiple Access (2016) DBs into SAS (9.4), as opposed to doing a bunch of proc import statements.  I cannot use the OLEDB or ODBC as I do not have proper drivers installed on my computer.  Any tips as to how to go about doing this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You don't state it clearly so I'm assuming there's a reason you can't just go and install the drivers.  As an alternative, why not dump them to CSV from within Access then just read in the flat files from SAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign a library to database path. All tables will show as datasets. SAS maintains both [Access and Excel facilities](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63181/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n1wvmggexroxgyn17rp61jml3cvn.htm) for easy library assignment.

Please note this is a live connection and live tables and changes here including deleting datasets will remove such tables. With Access you will see the locked file (.laccb) in use with below connection.

```
** ASSIGN LIBNAME;
libname accdata "C:\Path\To\Database.accdb";

** UNASSIGN LIBNAME;
libname accdata clear;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, however a lot of tables have names not conventional to SAS so without manually changing each one SAS throws an error at the first "-" or special character it sees.

Comment: Forgive me but that is above your original question. You can change the Access table names with Access VBA using its `TableDefs()` collection prior to assigning library. Do you know Access VBA? As a best practice, refrain from special characters and spaces in table names.

Comment: Not a VBA guru but that's a good idea, I should be able to scrap something together.  I personally know not to use special characters, but the data is coming from an outside source and they control the names unfortunately.

Comment: Got it. Please accept this answer if it helped and to confirm resolution of question.